# User Instagram Graph API without Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, api, graph, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Instagram Graph API from Facebook. I need the media, stories and some profile information like follower. The problem is, that many users have no Facebook page which is connected to a instagram account.

Is it possible to use the Instagram Graph API without Facebook Login? The best solutions would be a login via Instagram or login via Facebook but without required page. Have anyone a suggestion?

Comment: Have you find any solution??

Comment: Also looking for a solution

Comment: @Julian Wagner did you find one?

Answer (score 1):

I read through the documents and did a bunch of testing.
Here's what I think is necessary for using instagram Graph API as of 21-01-2021:

A facebook login to get fb access token
A page that connect to a business/creator account

We can get the connected instagram business/creator account's data by the token.
If users do not have facebook page is your concern, consider to use the instagram basic api instead.

I think it is possible to get ig data without facebook technically. Hope facebook get provide a clearer instruction and docs for developers in the future.